# Flat Shipping price per product using Drupal Commerce

Tags: 7, commerce

I've been beating my head against a wall trying to configure shipping in Drupal Commerce for a week now and so here I am! I have a Select or Other field in the product entity with a couple of choices:

- Free Shipping
- Call for Details
- Other (and the admin enters a flat price)

Again, this is entered on a per product basis, on the Commerce Product entity (not the node). My question is how do I update the shipping price based on this value? It should work as follows:

- Item 1 (shipping: $1.00)
- Item 2 (shipping: $4.00)
- Item 3 (shipping: Free)
- Item 4 (shipping: Call for Details)
- Item 5 (shipping: $1.00)
- **Total Shipping: $6.00**

Perhaps I'm doing this wrong. Any direction would be awesome. Thanks!

---

**This is the final working code:**

```
class CustomShipping extends CommerceShippingQuote {
  public function calculate_quote($currency_code, $form_values = array(), $order = NULL, $pane_form = NULL, $pane_values = NULL) {
    $order = $order ? $order : $this->order;
    $order_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('commerce_order', $order);
    $price = 0;
    // Loop through the products, and add costs.
    foreach ($order_wrapper->commerce_line_items as $line_item_wrapper) {
      if ($line_item_wrapper->commerce_product->field_shipping_price_other->value() > 1) {
          $price += ($line_item_wrapper->commerce_product->field_shipping_price_other->value()*100)*$line_item_wrapper->quantity->value();
      }
    }
    return array(array(
      'amount' => $price,
      'currency_code' => $currency_code,
      'label' => t('Custom Shipping label'),
      'quantity' => 1,
    ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using commerce shipping 1.x, you should do something like this:

**Disclaimer, this is written by memory.**

This is based on two fields on the product,

`field_shipping_type` containing the shipping type
`field_flat_rate` containing the actual rate for the product.

1. Create a custom module and add a folder for the shipping plugin, fx `plugins/quotes/custom_shipping`
2. Create the custom_shipping.inc with the plugin definition.

   ```
   <?php

   $plugin = array(
     'title' => t('Custom shipping'),
     'description' => t('Descriptive text.'),
     'handler' => array(
       'class' => 'CustomShipping',
       'parent' => 'quote_base'
     ),
     'price_component' => array(
      'title' => t('Shipping'),
      'display_title' => t('Shipping'),
      'weight' => -40,
     ),
   );
   ```
3. Create the actual shipping logic in the CustomShipping.class.php file in the same dir. All you need is something like this:

   ```
   class CustomShipping extends CommerceShippingQuote {
     public function calculate_quote($currency_code, $form_values = array(), $order = NULL, $pane_form = NULL, $pane_values = NULL) {
       $order = $order ? $order : $this->order;
       $order_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('commerce_order', $order);
       $price = 0;
       // Loop through the products, and add costs.
       foreach ($order_wrapper->commerce_line_items as $line_item_wrapper) {
         switch ($line_item_wrapper->commerce_product->field_shipping_type->value()) {
           case 'free':
             break;
           case 'flat_rate':
             $price += $line_item_wrapper->commerce_product->field_flat_rate->amount->value();
             break;
           case 'call_for_details':
             // Call for details
             break;
         }
       }
       return array(array(
         'amount' => $price,
         'currency_code' => $currency_code,
         'label' => t('Custom shipping method line item label'),
         'quantity' => 1,
       ));
     }
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks, I'm actually using shipping 2.x, but I don't see a reason I can't go with 1.x. It isn't as if it works right now! I'll let you know.

Comment: @Clive I did write the module after all ;)

Comment: I didn't realise that...still an impressive brain dump in my opinion!

Comment: I'm almost there. I made a couple of changes to the code itself, the issue I am having now involved quantity. If I have more than one of the item I need to multiply the shipping amount. Any pointers on what the var is for quantity?

Comment: `$line_item_wrapper->quantity->value()` I believe.

Comment: Boom. Gracias amigo.

Comment: So does this method work for Shipping 2.x?  If not, what are the differences and where can we look to find more information?  The in-line documentation in commerce_shipping.api.php doesn't mention any of this stuff.  Thanks.

Comment: In response to my above comment, updates on this issue are available over at [Documentation 1.x vs 2.x](https://drupal.org/node/1947102).